# Partial wakelock does not work on android wear

Tags: java, android, wear-os, wakelock, power-management

I'am gathering accelerometer data in my watchface and as soon as the device enter ambient mode the cpu is put to sleep.

I've tried adding a partial_wakelock on creation but it still does not work, A Full wakelock works fine but i want the benefits of having ambient mode such as burn in protection to work.

Any idea whats wrong?

```
        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        //wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "awake");

        wl = powerManager.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "MyWakelockTag");
```

The commented line does not work.

I aquire the wakelock in registration of the accelerometer and release it onDestroy.

It is a very frustrating problem and i can not find out what iam doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**In breif** it is normal. Relax.

For battery saving reason some Android devices go to sleep and disable bluetooth mode .  To become it active i have just found that only FULL_WAKE_LOCK works.  May be,  i'm bot right but this is my experince. The other options that helps to save battery must be disabled inside Android OS preference too.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html), you can obtain an instance of `PowerManager` class by calling `Context.getSystemService()`.

You may want to try using this:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```

instead of

```
powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
```

In addition to that, you cannot use [`ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP) and [`ON_AFTER_RELEASE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ON_AFTER_RELEASE) with [`PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK).

Please also note that any application using a WakeLock must request the `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` permission in an `<uses-permission>` element of the application's manifest.

Comment: ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP was added later just for testing if it made a diffrence. I tried your way before but no success, i will try on my moto360 if this i the manufacturers implementation of ambient mode that is the culprit or if it is googles own fault. The permission is set.